# Unable to Install epson L3210 printer in 22.04 ubuntu

Tags: dpkg, epson

Instalation is stopped after a message :
Unable to install epson-inkjet-printer-202101w:
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run ‘dpkg –configure-a’ to correct the problem

Comment: so, did you run `dpkg –configure-a` and what is the output ?

Comment: dpkg is installed then i installed lsb and then hv done update and upgrade.

Comment: in system setting my printer model is showing , a drop down list showing "printing now" and "printing completed" i heard the soung of printer head but paper comes out blank - no printing.